# New release of my app is not showing in some devices's App World

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I have already submit a new release of my app and it has been approved. Now I can download it but not everyone can. People with the same device I have does not get de updating info and when delete the app from their devices and comes into App World again, only find the older release they installed previously.

I think it happens on devices with v6 of OS but my app is developed from v5 and up.

Could anyone explain this wrong behaviour and why is it happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott is right.
Here's the official link explaining it

> It can take up to 7 days for all BlackBerry® smartphone users to see your upgraded release, new or changed screen shots, or new icons.

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1573156/What_Is_-_The_BlackBerry_App_World_storefront_cache.html?nodeid=1577562&vernum=0

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have set the appropriate OS versions for the COD files that you have uploaded?  I have also heard rumors that App World does not update simultaneously for all users.  That there is potentially some kind of a roll-out process where it may take several days for all users to see updates.

Comment: Yes, OS versions are correct. I'll wait to see what happens in the next hours. Thanks.